# Angular post-build step on Windows

Tags: angular, batch-file, ng-build

I'm running my build with `ng build --watch`, and I'd like to run a batch file after each build. How do I go about this?

Comment: If you want to run two processes in parallel from a package script, I've found `concurrently` useful. But if you're asking if Angular CLI exposes such a hook; see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build (it doesn't).

Comment: I've also looked for this functionality in Angular CLI many times, and nope, doesn't exist ):

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a build tool.

I recommend [GulpJS](https://gulpjs.com/)

In your gulpfile something like this:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

... 
gulp.task('your-batch-function-here'], function (cb) {
  <<your custom task here>>
});

gulp.task('ng-build', [], function (cb) {
  spawn('npm', ['run', 'build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
});

gulp.task('build', ['ng-build', 'your-batch-function-here'], function () {
});
```

If you start this with `gulp build`, it will
  1.  run ann npm run build command
  2. After it is finished, will run your batch function task (you must implement it as a gulp.task)

Comment: glad to help. Please consider to accept it as an answer.